# Elasticsearch conditional filters on docs with different fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elastalert

I have documents like:

```
Type 1 (stats from component A) -  
_sources {
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2015-11-02T06:50:11.170Z",
    "stat_type": 1,
    "ConnectionCount": 1,
    "ReceivedCount": 2,
    "AcceptedCount": 0,
    "host": "my-pc",
    "component_type": "A",
}

Type 2 (Stats from component B) - 
_sources {
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2015-11-02T06:50:11.170Z",
    "stat_type": 1,
    "SuccessCount": 2,
    "host": "my-pc",
    "component_type": "B",
}
```

From these two types of docs, I want to do following things -

1. If ReceivedCount from doctypeA is greater than 0, then get the
   SuccessCount from doctypeB.
2. If they don't match then alert using elastalert.

I have basic knowledge of elasticsearch and elastalert.

I tried to understand elasticserach scripts to query elasticsearch, but couldn't do it because different columns in two records.

Please guide.

Comment: I'm not sure ES's document model is suitable for the task you describe. Would you need to run this check periodically or in real-time when component B's data is available? BTW timestamp field seems to get deprecated and docs suggest you to use a normal datetime field and set its value explicitly. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-timestamp-field.html

Comment: @NikoNyrh I need to run this check periodically at the interval of 5 mins.  Thank you for the deprecated info.

Answer (score 0):

I was about to post and answer suggesting to use `nested` or `parent-child` documents to execute this "JOIN" but then I realized it is still impossible to create a query for "documents where field value of doc `A` is different from value of doc `B`.

You could use [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) to get distinct values of `AcceptedCount`, and then for each distinct value `x` query "documents WHERE AcceptedCount = `x` AND SuccessCount != `x`" (using `must` and `must_not` with [term filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-term-filter.html)). This shouldn't have terribly bad performance if the number of distinct `AcceptedCount` values is low, different filters can be put in a single `should` block so a single ES query is sufficient.

This query can be executed on documents where `component_type`s `A` and `B` are stored in [nested documents](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-nested-type.html). If there are other component types then you'd need nested documents for those as well. Documents' `_id` would be generated from the "natural key" of `timestamp`, `host` and `start_type`.

Comment: It would be simpler to just use a SQL database and do a JOIN or something, i think ES is beneficial here only if you are already using for example Logstash and Kibana.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am already using logstash and kibana, so its not possible to use sql db. I will see if these are nested documents. Thank you very much!